# How to include sub elements with custom angular directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

## Current HTML

```
<g class='entity'>
  <rect />
  <circle />
  ...
</g>
```

## New / Desired HTML

```
<box>
  <rect />
  <circle />
  ...
</box>
```

## Simple Directive

```
app.directive('box', ['$document', function ($document) {
    return {
        restrict : 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: "<g class='entity'></g>"
    };
}]);
```

## Result in DOM

```
<g class='entity'>... everything missing here ... </g>
```

I would like the sub child elements to be kept in place.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called transclusion.
If you add **transclude: true** to your directive definition all the child elements will be kept. Template will override just **box** element, but keep the inner content.

```
app.directive('box', ['$document', function ($document) {
return {
    restrict : 'E',
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    template: "<g class='entity'></g>"
};
```

}]);

Comment: For some reason I have tried this twice but it does not affect anything? I am using AngularJS 1.5x.

Comment: Don't you need to put the `ng-transclude` directive in the template to specify where the child elements get output? As in, `template: "<g class='entity' ng-transclude></g>"`?

Comment: Actually no, if you don't provide ng-transclude angular assumes it automatically on top element (g in this case). You need ng-transclude only if you want to define more complex DOM structure and want to have transclusion on some inner element - <g><span ng-transclude></span></g>

See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lt7aP/2503/

Comment: @JoeClay your suggestion worked! ng-transclude on the <g> tag, however, now I have all the SVG HTML present, but none of it is actually rendering on the screen as it was before.

Comment: @Missingmanual: I stand corrected! Personally I prefer to be explicit still, but it's good to know that feature exists.

Comment: @لَاإِلٰهَإِلَّاالله: I'm not sure where to go from there - I don't really make use of SVG myself. Hopefully someone else will be able to get you the rest of the way there.

Comment: @لَاإِلٰهَإِلَّاالله: If you would provide an example on plnkr or jsfiddle I might be able to help you. Didn't application complain initially for having <box> in svg element? I'm pretty sure this element doesn't exist in svg definition.
Or have you maybe forgotten to wrap everything in SVG tag?